# Change Firebase project for production app with Google Authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-oauth

I need to change Firebase Project of production app with google authentication.

My app is working with a firebase project and a backend server from which I can force users to update my app to the latest version after login with version the user has. Because of that, I hope I can change the Firebase project where I do the authentication with Google.

I can't use old pair Package Name / SHA-1 in new Firebase project, but I can use old package name with NEW SHA-1, right?

So, users with old versions will login with old firebase project and after upgrade my app they will login with with new firebase project, right?

If so, users won't need to uninstall my app, right?

Now, how can I change the SHA-1 in Android Studio?

Comment: What do you want to do? I can't understand.

Comment: Simply change the firebase project from one google oauth application to another similar one with google oauth without interrupting service to users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I understand you are trying to do is the following.

1. You want to associate your app to new firebase project
2. You want to keep you old user base intact.

You have asked if you can change the SHA-1 of the app the answer is no without changing the signature of the app that could change everything and is not an option.

What you could do instead is use two different firebase projects in a single app and write your own logic to manage the users. You can follow this link https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html here the author has explained how to go about it. 
 you can also look up for similar solutions for the problem. Hope this helps in some way and please try to make you questions precise.

Comment: My intention would be to migrate from an oauth google to a Firebase project with oauth Google during the app upgrade by users. So far, user data is stored on my server and not on Firebase. My real need is to start using real time databases and neither the registered user indication I am getting on Firebase even with oauth authentication achieved. From your answer, I understand that changing the SHA-1 key is not possible and I can understand why. I had already tried upgrad legacy project along with existing Google API project with no results. I will try once again.

Comment: @AvinashJoshi Great answer! Now I understand what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I understood your need wrongly!

You have users and want to sign them in to a new firebase project with interrupting your current users?!

I believe what you need to use is the [custom Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth)

whenever the user logs in, you produce a token in you current project and pass it on to the new project.

As for:

> backend server from which I can force users to update my app

you can also achieve this in firebase, hopefully the backend server is not just for this!

Comment: In my case, I've been authenticating users with google oauth in my backend server. Everything works fine and will continue like this. There are in-app services that for what I need more control over the data. After authenticating with Google, the application sends a token to my server that returns account information to user. All this working perfectly. Now there is a new need to connect users to a real-time database and Firebase is perfect for that. The problem was, I couldn't connect to Firebase, so the easiest solution I thought would be to create a new project in FB but that just can't be.